# Difference between ColorTween vs Tween<Color> and IntTween vs Tween<int>?

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the difference between

```
ColorTween vs Tween<Color>
```

and

```
IntTween vs Tween<int>
```

If everything can be handled by `Tween<T>`, why these `XXXTween` exist?

Comment: no, not everything can be handled by `Tween<T>` - see `Tween` official documentation for more info (section `"Types with special considerations"`)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your response, please write it as answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: sure, your welcome, feel free to write a self answer then

Answer (score 1):

***tldr;* You can use your own implementation of `Tween<Color>` or just `ColorTween`. `ColorTween` or `IntTween` are just built in implementations for common use case. But for a unique use case you definitely need to implement `Tween<CustomCase>`**

The use case for `Tween` is simple, it spits out specific values in between a range of given values. In fact the name `Tween` comes from the word **be*TWEEN***. In general you can have your own implementation of Tween or Tween which serve the same purpose as `ColorTween` or `IntTween`.

Since, there are some use cases like tween-ing between a bunch of colors or a bunch of integers or a bunch of `BorderRadius`. For these purposes, flutter developers have a bunch of classes for these common use cases like `ColorTween`, `IntTween` or [BorderRadiusTween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BorderRadiusTween-class.html).

But lets say you have your own custom use case for which there's no implementation for `Tween` class. For example you want to spit out [Rect-s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect-class.html) between a specific range of co-ordinates. In that case you need to implement `Tween<Rect>` since there isn't any implementation available in the flutter API as far as I know.